# SQL How to add if else conditions in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

Table A consists of firstname, secondname, lastname, msisdn, registrationdate.. table b have firstname, secondname, lastname, msisdn, registrationdate and a few other columns - but i only want to consider these mentioned 5 columns.
I have something like this

```
SELECT SELECT A.MSISDN,A.FIRSTNAME,A.SECONDNAME,A.LASTNAME,A.REGDATE, B.MSISDN,B.FIRSTNAME,B.SECONDNAME,B.LASTNAME,B.REGDATE 
FROM TABLE1 A
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.MSISDN = B.MSISDN
WHERE A.FIRSTNAME != B.FIRSTNAME 
OR A.LASTNAME != B.LASTNAME
```

Previously i only considered firstname, lastname from table A and checked for mismatch in table B, but i'm getting thousands of records as results and i wanted narrow down the search.

How do i include an if else case here so that

```
if a.firstname == b.firstname && a.secondname == b.lastname - Ignore this record.

if a.firstname == b.firstname && a.lastname == b.lastname - Ignore this record.

if a.firstname == b.firstname && a.lastname == b.secondname- Ignore this record.

if a.firstname not equal to b.firstname - show this record as result

if a.firstname == b.firstname && a.secondname not equal to b.lastname - show this record as result
```

else show all the records as results that doesn't fall into any of these above cases. Also if it is possible, please include a solution to ignore capital letters and small letters while checking for mismatches.

[image: Please find the sample data here]
the problem here is, after executing the query from @sagi, in the results i'm getting the rows which has perfect match between first,second and lastnames but has a different registration date - as we are not considering registration date in the query, will it impact the results?

Comment: Use AND/OR. And parentheses.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by this question and its answers. I'm probably missing something obvious, but isn't the original query already fine?

Comment: @Aioros the original query is just checking the firstname and lastname for mismatches. but i needed something to check for other scenarios like a.secondname == b.lastname etc inorder to narrow down the query results.

Comment: Oh well, there it is, the obvious bit I was missing.

Comment: @Aioros can you explain it to me?

Comment: Well, actually I'm not sure anymore. I think now that the OP wants to add conditions about the pair firstname/secondname being the same as another firstname/lastname, but I don't think the accepted answer addresses that.

Comment: @SaiAvinash, check my updated answer below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM TABLE1 A
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.MSISDN = B.MSISDN
WHERE (UPPER(B.FIRSTNAME),UPPER(B.LASTNAME)) NOT IN ((UPPER(A.FIRSTNAME),UPPER(A.LASTNAME)),(UPPER(A.FIRSTNAME),UPPER(A.SECONDNAME)))
```

No need for `IF` , if this condition returns true, it means all your conditions are met, and either `first_name` is different or `last_name` is .

Comment: this works. meeting all the required conditions. thanks @sagi

Comment: is it a MySql solution ? I don't reconize this syntax (and sybase either ;) )

Comment: @AxelH Yes, it should work on almost any RDBMS (Don't know about sybase though) .

Comment: @sagi Almost any RDBMS except SQL Server, where this syntax isn't valid.

Comment: @sagi (A, B) is not a valid expression in SQL Server, so it doesn't work with the Equals operator either. It's *always* a syntax error.

Comment: Oops, that's a typo, i missed a parentheses. Thanks for the catch @kevin .

Comment: @sagi No problem.  Just curious though, I still don't get what this does that is different from the query in the question

Comment: i was going through all files and noticed this query is giving me the records which are matching 100% in both the tables. a.firstname, secondname, lastname==b.firstname, secondname, lastname. Also i did not get a chance to go through all the records earlier so checked a couple of records and they seemed good. now when i went through all the records, i see this condition is not getting ignored 'if a.firstname==b.firstname and  a.secondname==b.lastname - this record is still showing up as output. sorry for not checking the records 100% correctly earlier, i just got some freetime

Comment: Oh , there are extra columns other then what I have used in my query? That is why you should always post tables structure, input and expected output. Please add the required information and I will fix the solution @saiavinash .

Comment: @sagi i've edited the question. i though i included the table structures. please let me know if the question is still unclear, i'll try to add more points. thanks again :)

Comment: @kevin Huh you were right , I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: @sagi i'm confused now. can you create a chat room so that i can explain you more clearly. i'm not sure how i can invite you to chat..

Comment: I think we just need to post a few more messages and SO will offer it to us :)

Comment: I just entered your chat with JayValkyr -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123409/discussion-between-jayvalkyr-and-sai-avinash @SaiAvinash

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use a `CASE` expression.

They look like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, (case when (action = 2 and state = 0) 
 THEN
      1 
 ELSE
      0 
 END)
 as state from tbl1;
```

Comment: You will still have all the records with a CASE... so you need to use this in a derived query to filtrer the result of you case column.

Answer (score 4):

This will do it. Basically you just need exclude results where both, firstname and second/lastname are matching.

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM TABLE1 A
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.MSISDN = B.MSISDN
WHERE (NOT (A.FIRSTNAME = B.FIRSTNAME AND A.SECONDNAME = B.LASTNAME))
AND (NOT (A.FIRSTNAME = B.FIRSTNAME AND A.LASTNAME = B.LASTNAME))
```

Comment: is there a way to exclude/ignore the records which has a.firstname and a.lastname matches with b.firstname and b.lastname even if a.secondname is empty but b.secondname has some data in it? can this search ignore capital and small letters? that would narrow down the search results to a major extent. thanks

Comment: @SaiAvinash this query excludes all records where a.firstname/b.firstname and a.lastname/b.lastname matches regardless of what's in a.secondname or b.secondname. Additionally, use LOWER -function to make the query case insensitive

Comment: i guess those extra records in results are due to the capital small letters in both tables. is there a way to just ignore the case-sensitivity?

Comment: I was going though the records and see that the records with exact same details in table a and table b showed up in the result.. [this record](http://imgur.com/a/kUhH3)

Comment: @SaiAvinash are you sure that the values are exactly same? Not that one of the values contain white-space or something like that? You shouldn't need to use lower -function as select statements are insensitive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123409/discussion-between-jayvalkyr-and-sai-avinash).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CASE` to draft a IF then like Query .

As per Doc
CASE is used to provide if-then-else type of logic to SQL. There are two formats: The first is a Simple CASE expression, where we compare an expression to static values. The second is a Searched CASE expression, where we compare an expression to one or more logical conditions.

Example

```
SELECT CASE ("column_name") 
  WHEN "value1" THEN "result1" 
  WHEN "value2" THEN "result2" 
  ... 
  [ELSE "resultN"] 
  END
FROM "table_name";
```

Comment: You will still have all the records with a CASE... so you need to use this in a derived query to filtrer the result of you case column.